# Not able to inflate custom array adapter

Tags: android, listview, time

I am using the code below to get three strings and one integer to create text view in list view using custom array adapter and custom class

```
package com.shyam.android.tamillanguagelearningapp;

    /**
     * Created by MANI on 12/8/2016.
     */


    // it caontains two tralatio words as
        // declaration of the class
    public class Word {

        /** english translation*/
        // state of word class
        private String mEnglishTranslation;

        /** tamil translation*/
        private String mTamilTranslation;
        /** tamil number*/
        private String mTamilNumber;
        /** english number*/
       private int mEnglishNumber;




    // constrauctor to tke two words

        public Word(String englishTranslation,String tamilTranslation ,String tamilNumber,int englishNumber){

            mEnglishTranslation = englishTranslation;
            mTamilTranslation = tamilTranslation;
            mTamilNumber = tamilNumber;
            mEnglishNumber = englishNumber;

        }
    // methods of the class
        public String getmEnglishTranslation(){
            return mEnglishTranslation;
        }

        public String getmTamilTranslation(){
            return mTamilTranslation;
        }

        public String getmTamilNumber(){
            return mTamilNumber;
        }

        public int getmEnglishNumber(){
            return mEnglishNumber;
        }



    }



    end****


    //custome array adaptor file

    package com.shyam.android.tamillanguagelearningapp;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    /**
     * Created by MANI on 12/8/2016.
     */

    public class WordAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Word> {

        /**
         * This is our own custom constructor (it doesn't mirror a superclass constructor).
         * The context is used to inflate the layout file, and the list is the data we want
         * to populate into the lists.
         *
         //* @param context        The current context. Used to inflate the layout file.
         //* @param words A List of AndroidFlavor objects to display in a list
         */
        public WordAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Word> words) {
            // Here, we initialize the ArrayAdapter's internal storage for the context and the list.
            // the second argument is used when the ArrayAdapter is populating a single TextView.
            // Because this is a custom adapter for two TextViews and an ImageView, the adapter is not
            // going to use this second argument, so it can be any value. Here, we used 0.
            super(context, 0, words);
        }



        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // Check if the existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
            View listItemView = convertView;
            if(listItemView == null) {
                listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                        R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            }

            // Get the {@link AndroidFlavor} object located at this position in the list
            Word currentWord = getItem(position);

            // Find the TextView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID version_name
            TextView tamilTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.tamil_text_view);
            // Get the version name from the current AndroidFlavor object and
            // set this text on the name TextView
            tamilTextView.setText(currentWord.getmTamilTranslation());

            // Find the TextView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID version_number
            TextView englsihTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.english_text_view);
            // Get the version number from the current AndroidFlavor object and
            // set this text on the number TextView
            englsihTextView.setText(currentWord.getmEnglishTranslation());

            // Find the TextView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID version_number
            TextView tamilNumber = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.tamil_number_text_view);
            // Get the version number from the current AndroidFlavor object and
            // set this text on the number TextView
            tamilNumber.setText(currentWord.getmTamilNumber());

            // Find the TextView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID version_number
           TextView englishNumber = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.english_number_text_view);
            // Get the version number from the current AndroidFlavor object and
            // set this text on the number TextView
           englishNumber.setText(currentWord.getmEnglishNumber());

            // Find the ImageView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID list_item_icon
           // ImageView iconView = (ImageView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_icon);
            // Get the image resource ID from the current AndroidFlavor object and
            // set the image to iconView
           // iconView.setImageResource(currentAndroidFlavor.getImageResourceId());

            // Return the whole list item layout (containing 2 TextViews and an ImageView)
            // so that it can be shown in the ListView
            return listItemView;
        }

    }
```

**activity file**

```
package com.shyam.android.tamillanguagelearningapp;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.widget.ListView;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class NumbersActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.word_list);
           // createing string array to store words

            //String[] words = new String[10];
            // storing data

           // words[0 ]= "One";
           // words[1]= "Two";
           // words[2]= "Three";
           // words[3]= "Four";
           // words[4]= "Five";
           // words[5]= "Six";
           // words[6]= "Seven";
           // words[7]= "Eight";
           // words[8]= "Nine";
           // words[9]= "Ten";

           // Log.v("NumbersActivity","the number in place of words 0 is = " + words[0]);
            //Log.v("NumbersActivity","the number in place of words 1 is = " + words[1]);

    // create an arrary list
            ArrayList<Word> words = new ArrayList<Word>();
               // add data to array lsit
           // words.add("One");
                    words.add(new Word("Zero","சுழியம்","௦",0));
            words.add(new Word("One","ஒன்று","௧",1));
            words.add(new Word("Two","இரண்டு","௨",2));
            words.add(new Word("Three","மூன்று","௩",3));
            words.add(new Word("Four","நான்கு","௪",4));
            words.add(new Word("Five","ஐந்து","௫",5));
            words.add(new Word("Six","ஆறு","௬",6));
            words.add(new Word("Seven","ஏழு","௭",7));
            words.add(new Word("Eight","எட்டு","௮",8));
            words.add(new Word("Nine","ஒன்பது","௯",9));
            words.add(new Word("Ten","பத்து","௰",10));


            //words.add("Two");
           // words.add("Three");
            //words.add("Four");
            //words.add("Five");
           // words.add("Six");
           // words.add("Seven");
           // words.add("Eight");
           // words.add("Nine");
           // words.add("Ten");


           // Log.v("NumbersActivity"," The number in place of words 0 is = " + words.get(0));
           // Log.v("NumbersActivity"," The number in place of words 6 is = " + words.get(5));
            //Log.v("NumbersActivity"," The number in place of words 10 is = " + words.get(9));


            // /creating thre view child and add data and displaing it and adding to the paretn
          // LinearLayout rootView = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.rootView);
            //TextView wordview = new TextView(this);
            //wordview.setText(words.get(0));
           // rootView.addView(wordview);

            //using loops to do the above code

           // int index = 0;
           // while (index<words.size()){
                // create anew lik text view that display the wordview
                //and the view as a child to the rootview
               // TextView wordview = new TextView(this);
                //wordview.setText(words.get(index));
                // rootView.addView(wordview);
                //update the counter variable
               // index = index + 1;

            // using for loop to do the above code



            //for(int index = 0 ; index < words.size(); index ++){
                // create the text view
                //TextView wordview = new TextView(this);
                //set the text to be word at the current index
               // wordview.setText(words.get(index));
                // add theis textview as another child tothe root view of this layout
                 //rootView.addView(wordview);
            //}


            WordAdapter adapter =

                    new WordAdapter(this,words);

            ListView listView =(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

            }
```

Its not working for me. Please guide me on this.

Comment: use [this](https://gist.github.com/pskink/2dd4d17a93caf02ff696533e82f952b0) generic adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
englishNumber.setText(currentWord.getmEnglishNumber());
```

into

```
englishNumber.setText(currentWord.getmEnglishNumber()+"");
```

TextView#setText

```
 public final void setText(@StringRes int resid) {
    setText(getContext().getResources().getText(resid));
}
```

Comment: thanks it worked for me ,thank u. i will be continuing my app developement.thank you once again.